# Animation | Wait until the first animation still run

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I try to create my own slide show for a personal use, and I have faced with an issue.

In my jQuery plugin, I have create an Object that operates my plugin. The code is structured in the following form:

```
(
    function($)
    {
        $.fn.wplSlider = function(options)
        {
            var slider     =   this;

            var settings    =   $.extend(
                {
                    'animationSpeed'    :   750,
                    'animationEasing'   :   null,
                    'animationAutoStart':   true,
                    'pauseTime'         :   3500
                },
                options
            );

            var methods =   {
                animationRun        :   false,
                totalSlides         :   0,
                init                :   function()
                {
                    // This method initiating the slide show elements
                },
                slidesStatus        :   function()
                {
                    // This method initiating the slides status
                },
                slideNumber         :   function()
                {
                    // Assign a number to each slide
                },
                getSlidesAmount     :   function()
                {
                    // Get the amount of slides
                },
                next                :   function()
                {
                    // Prepare the next slide that will be displayed
                },
                prev                :   function()
                {
                    // Prepare the next slide that will be displayed
                },
                goTo                :   function(item)
                {
                    // Prepare the specified slide
                },
                slideOut            :   function()
                {
                    // Slide out the current slide
                    slider.find('li[data-status="current"] .container').animate(
                        {
                            top :   '-75px'
                        },
                        600
                    );

                    slider.find('li[data-status="current"] span, li[data-status="current"] a').animate(
                        {
                            opacity :   0
                        },
                        600
                    );
                },
                slideIn             :   function()
                {
                    // Slide in the current slide
                    $('li[data-status="current"]').animate(
                        {
                            'opacity'   :   1
                        },
                        650
                    );
                }
            }

            /* Allow chainability */
            return this.each(
                function()
                {
                    methods.init();
                    methods.slideOut();
                    methods.next();
                    methods.slideIn();
                }
            );
        }
    }
)(jQuery);
```

With the above code, the problem is that, when I execute the slideOut / next / slideIn the steps are very fast.

More specific, the slideIn() is execute at the same time with the slideOut().

Is there a way to make the slideIn() to be executed only after the slideOut() is completed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make the slideIn() to be executed only after the
>   slideOut() is completed ?

Yes you can with the below code.

Below code will allow you to run slideIn() function will be executed when the slideOut() function has been executed.

```
$.when(methods.slideOut())
  .then(methods.slideIn());
```

***[Read more](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)***

Comment: If you want to go a little bit deeper in knowledge: This works because methods like slideIn implement the Deferred "Interface". See this reference: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/